# JQuery and modified autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm just starting with jquery so maybe there's a really easy way to do this... but I would like to have a form with an input element, where a user can enter a filename, and then next to it a listbox or something similar where it displays the folder(s) in which files that match the input pattern are displayed.

Ideally I wouldnt start searching the folders until I have 3 characters or so as well since there may be a lot of folders.

The autocomplete that comes with jquery out of the box seems to have some of what, I wan't but being a jquery n00b I'm not sure if that is the right way to approach this or I should do something else.

Thanks!

Edit:  Here's how I'm getting the folders:

```
var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
var folder = fso.GetFolder("top/level/directory");

// Iterate over folders
var subFlds = new Enumerator(folder.SubFolders);
var subFolder;

for (; !subFlds.atEnd() ; subFlds.moveNext()) {
    subFolder = subFlds.item() + "";
    if (subFolder.match(/* My input string goes here */)) {
         break;
    }
}
```

This isn't the exact way I would use this for the use case I describe, but it shows what I'm doing to go through folders.

Comment: @Jojan: I'm searching the folders via ActiveXObject.  This is some legacy code- it's a standalone html file, it's not ever served up through a webserver (I didn't write it, I just want to tweak it)

Comment: Can you paste the javascript which is fetching the folders?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you need to get familiar with the jQuery UI Autocomplete documentation:

http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

I hate to just leave a RTFM response, but it is important for you to be familiar with the widget so that you can ask a more precise question.

The page allows you to view source and see exactly what their demo was using to operate.  And the API documentation has a plethora of more examples.

If you have any specific questions on it, let us know.

Comment: Nope, a RTFM is fair- I just didn't know if this was something kind of out of the box or not.

Comment: The autocomplete widget is there for you, but you will likely have to implement a custom function for the `source` option.  Your question wasn't clear if you were having trouble with the autocomplete widget, the concept of how to list the available folders, or both.

Comment: I was able to use the autocomplete widget ok.  I wasnt sure however how to have it set the results into a different element, and not search until 3 characters have been entered.

Comment: `minLength` option to control 3 character minimum.  I'm not quite sure what you mean by "set the results into a different element"... There is an `appendTo` option that may do what you want, but you could always implement a custom `response` or `select` function and do whatever you want.  If you have specific questions on these in the documentation I would post another question specifically about that on here.

Comment: I think the appendTo is exactly what I need... the search input is coming from a text input field, but the results need to be put into a list box or something similar.